# Changing cart image based on cart item

Tags: magento2, cart, magento2.2.2, mini-cart

I am trying to change the cart image based on my cart item configuration. But it seems like `Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Item\Renderer::getImage` receives the original `Product` model class and not the cart item product.

When adding the item to the cart I have added custom data with `$product->addCustomOption('my_option', $data)` and in `$data` is a generated base64 encoded image of the product. Which I would like to display in the cart and minicart.

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: may help this link https://magecomp.com/blog/set-base-image-instead-of-thumbnail-image-in-minicart-of-magento-2/

Answer (score 1):

I don't understood well the question, but if you want to change which product's image of configurable product will be showed in cart and minicart, in latest Magento version you can do it in: Store-> Configuration-> Sales-> Checkout-> Shopping Cart-> **Configurable Product Image** Where you can choose between: ***Product Thumbnail Itself*** or ***Parent Product Thumbnail***

Answer (score 0):

I **don't think you would able to changes** the cart image by changing anything at `Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Item\Renderer::getImage`.

Best idea in my view that work on template file means working on `.phtml`.

If you have your custom option `'my_option'` then  show our custom option image else show image using `<?= $block->getImage($block->getProductForThumbnail(), 'cart_page_product_thumbnail')->toHtml() ?>`

First, you  **need to find out cart your items render phtml file**, you don't have any customization then `cart/item/default.phtml` is the file from where **the images are showing at cart page**.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I will have to test it when I get back to the office.

Answer (score 0):

I don´t know if I have undestood you correctly, but this is what I have done to show images on the minicart:

1. Go to: `/app/design/frontend/Venustheme/mohawk/Magento_Checkout/templates/cart/minicart.phtml`

This is my code:

```
<?php if ($grandTotal < 0.01): ?>

<img src="/pub/media/wysiwyg/image_folder/1.png" />

<?php endif ?>

<?php if ($grandTotal > 0.01 AND $grandTotal < 120): ?>

<img src="/pub/media/wysiwyg/image_folder/2.png" />

<?php endif ?>
```

Depending the minicart subtotal price, it shows a image or another.

Oh, and you must declare de variable "subtotal", that is:

```
$subTotal = $cart->getQuote()->getSubtotal();
```

RESULT:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I will have to test it when I get back to the office.

Answer (score -1):

In this topic we will do How to Change Product Image in Minicart

Step 1: Create di.xml file

Step 2: Create Image.php file

Product image in minicart will getten to  show by function doGetItemData() in Magento\Checkout\CustomerData\DefaultItem class but this function is protected, so we cannot use plugin on it. Instead, it extends from Magento\Checkout\CustomerData\AbstractItem and use function getItemData()

First We need to create registration and module file as per structure of magento 2 then follow below steps.

Step 1: Create di.xml file

Create di.xml file in app/code/[Name_Space]/[Your_Module]/etc/frontend

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<type name="Magento\Checkout\CustomerData\AbstractItem">
     <plugin name="Change_Product_Image_In_Minicart" type="[Name_Space]\[Your_Module]\Plugin\Minicart\Image" sortOrder="1"/>
</type>
</config>
```

Step 2: Create Image.php file

Create Image.php file in app/code/[Name_Space][Your_Module]\Plugin\Minicart

```
<?php

namespace [Name_Space]\[Your_Module]\Plugin\Minicart;

class Image
{

    public function aroundGetItemData($subject, $proceed, $item)
    {

        $result = $proceed($item);

        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($result['product_id']);

        /* thum url */ 
        $storeManager = $objectManager->create('Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface'); 
        $currentStore = $storeManager->getStore();
        $mediaUrl = $currentStore->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA);

        if($product->getThumbnail()){
            $result['product_image']['src'] = $mediaUrl.$product->getThumbnail();
        }
        else{
            $result['product_image']['src'];
        }
        return $result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't use object manager, a full product load is bad practice.